# Auto-import Typescript sub-mobule instead of parent module in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

VSCode editor supports Typescript module auto-import. For a library like lodash, it automatically and conviniently adds the following correct import, once `sortBy` is typed anywhere in the code:

```
import { sortBy } from "lodash-es";
```

However, I would like to import all lodash functions from their submodules, like that:

```
import sortBy from "lodash-es/sortBy";
```

Is it possible to somehow blacklist top level module `"lodash-es"`, so that VSCode imports from submodule like `"lodash-es/sortBy"`?

I have a tslint rule https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/import-blacklist/ configured, so it prohibits top level import from `"lodash-es"` at lint time. But in the editor I still have to manually fix every autoimport.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the TypeScript auto-import source code and I'm pretty sure there's currently no way to do this short of forking `@types/lodash-es` and restructuring it to remove the exports from the top-level module.  I tried declaring my own `lodash-es` module with no exports that would shadow the real `lodash-es` top-level module, but that caused the type declaration for `lodash-es/sortBy` to generate an error.  I'd encourage you to [file a suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues) for the blacklisting.

Comment: Thanks for detailed (though unfortunate) answer and suggestion! Shouldn't this suggestion go into https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues? Or they are using some language services being developed as part of https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues project?

Comment: Indeed, VS Code uses the TypeScript language services for auto imports.